# iOS: PC/Mac connection detection

Tags: iphone, ios, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [An application to check iPhone connection with USB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426258/an-application-to-check-iphone-connection-with-usb)

As far as i know it's possible to detect when iPhone is charging, but is it possible to detect that iPhone is connected to a PC/Mac usb port?

On the iPhone side, sure. And with public framworks only.

Comment: IOKit has been around for quite a while now, I'm surprised you haven't heard of it.

Comment: Private frameworks are not allowed.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder that i didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is only way is to check for the charging. And no ways to detect a connection to PC/Mac usb port without using hacks or private frameworks.